# Using an Esrog that has on it Kedushas Shvi'is

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shmita

There will be a question this coming Sukkos (as there was somewhat last sukkos as well -- according to some opinions) because the esrogim will have kedushas shvi'is (the ones grown in Israel) If there is an "inyun" or if one should make it a "point" to use an esrog that has on it kedushas shvi'is. Is it at all a "hiddur" in the mitzvah? Better to use? Better not to use? Obviously there is a question about selling them however this is generally taken care of as they are sold with otzer beis din and a standard price is set.